# Bios cannot find windows and fedora booter

Tags: windows-10, bios, fedora, uefi

I've tried to install Fedora near Windows 10. When Fedora installer confirms that installation finished, I rebooted the computer and then BIOS haven't been seeing Fedora booter, no Windows booter (under booter I underestimate loader).

And here I'm using Fedora live installer from my visible USB. I've seen that this partitions exists, but BIOS do not see this.

All what I've googled is not usable because this methods needs Windows Recovery Disk or flash and I haven't another computer now.

P.S: I can't post images.

Comment: You can post images and someone else can inline them for you. Please do; your post could benefit from more information.